# Android Compose Paging 3 - Loading all pages at once without scrolling in LazyColumn with network call and no inner scrolls

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-mvvm, android-paging, android-paging-3

I'm working on an Android Compose project where I'm using Paging 3 along with a LazyColumn to display a list of items fetched from a network call. The default behavior of Paging 3 is to load pages based on `prefetchDistance` as the user scrolls, but in my case, it is loading around 15 pages, each containing 10 records on launch of the screen.
I have tried setting the `prefetchDistace` to 10, but it doesnt work.

Here is my code:
**ViewModel**

```
class ShowAllNotificationsViewModel @Inject constructor(private val pagingSource: NotificationPagingSource) :
    BaseViewModel() {


    private val _uiState =
        MutableStateFlow<UIState<BaseResponseModel<NotificationResponseModel?>>>(UIState.StateLoading)
    val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    private val _isRefreshing = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isRefreshing = _isRefreshing.asStateFlow()


    val items: Flow<PagingData<NotificationModel>> = Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 10,
            prefetchDistance = 5,
            enablePlaceholders = false,
        ),
        pagingSourceFactory = { pagingSource }
    )
        .flow
        .cachedIn(viewModelScope)

    fun refreshData() {
        pagingSource.invalidate()
    }
}
```

**PagingSource:**

```
class NotificationPagingSource @Inject constructor(val requestNotificationsUseCase: GetNotificationsUseCase) :
    PagingSource<String, NotificationModel>() {

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<String>): LoadResult<String, NotificationModel> {
        Timber.e(IllegalStateException())
        Timber.d("load params = $params")
        val responseModel = requestNotificationsUseCase(params.key)
        val result = responseModel?.getAsResult();
        result?.let {
            return@load when (result) {
                is Result.Error<*>,
                Result.Loading,
                is Result.SessionTimeoutError<*> -> {
                    LoadResult.Error(
                        SessionTimeoutException()
                    )
                }

                is Result.Success -> {

                    LoadResult.Page(
                        result.value.data?.notifications ?: listOf(),
                        prevKey = null,
                        nextKey = result.value.data?.lastId,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        return LoadResult.Error(
            IllegalStateException()
        )
    }

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<String, NotificationModel>): String? {
        Timber.d("getRefreshKey = state = $state")
        return null
    }
}
```

**UI :**

```
 @Composable
    fun ShowAllNotificationCompose(items: LazyPagingItems<NotificationModel>) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Black)
        ) {
            Timber.d("ShowAllNotificationCompose : state = ${items.loadState}")
            HeaderCompose()

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
            ) {
                val listState = rememberLazyListState()

                LazyColumn(
                    modifier = Modifier,
                    state = listState
                ) {
                    items(
                        count = items.itemCount,
                        key = {
                            items[it]?.id ?: 0
                        }
                    ) {
                        val notificationModel = items[it]
                        if (notificationModel != null) {
                            NotificationItem(item = notificationModel)
                        } else {
                            NotificationShimmerItem()
                        }
                    }
                   if (items.loadState.append == LoadState.Loading) {
                        items(2) {
                            NotificationShimmerItem()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to modify this setup to ensure that pagination request are invoked only after reaching the `prefectchDistance`.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in your `key`:

```
key = { items[it]?.id ?: 0 }
```

when you call `LazyPagingItems::get` it notifies Paging of the item access which can trigger page load. From the docs:

> Returns the presented item at the specified position, notifying Paging of the item access to trigger any loads necessary to fulfill prefetchDistance.

And the `key` is called for all the items immediately, not only when they are displayed. So for key, you should use the [`peek`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/compose/LazyPagingItems#peek(kotlin.Int)) function. Or you can use [`itemKey`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/compose/LazyPagingItems#(androidx.paging.compose.LazyPagingItems).itemKey(kotlin.Function1)), which is using peek internally.

```
key = { items.peek(it)?.id ?: 0 }

key = items.itemKey { it.id }
```